# Can I upload multiple images using Laravel 5.3.31?

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

I am trying to upload multiple images in my project.
I was able to change my input filed to multiple, and change it into an array.
However, even though I try to upload 2 images, I always wind up with an array that has only one member

I created a file input which I set to muiltple, and changed the name to an array.

Here is the code  In the controller I have

```
[
            'name' => 'images[]',
            'label' => '',
            'widget' => 'file',
             'widget_attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'multiple' => true,
            ],
           // 'widget_only' => null,
            'callback' => function($field, $row){
                 if ($row && $row->estimate_status_id == 5) {
                    $field['widget'] = 'text';
                }
                $files = \Storage::files('westims/pictures/' .    
  $row->site_id . '/' . $row->id);

                if (count($files) > 0){
                    $field['preview'] = '';
                    foreach ($files as $file){
                        $field['preview'] .= ' <a href="' . 
url("admin/docs?path=$file") . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . 
 url("admin/docs?path=$file") . '" style="max-height:100px"/> 
 </a>';
                    }
                } else {
                    $field['preview'] = trans('westims.no-images');
                }
                
                if(count($files) >=30 ) {
                    $field['widget'] = 'text';
                }

                return $field;
            },
                'column_span' => $this->detailColumns,
            ],
```

Here is where I try to save the pictures

**strong text**

```
if (Input::hasFile('images')){
            $file_count = 
count(\Storage::files('westims/pictures/' . $row->site_id . '/' . $row->id));
           if ($file_count < 30){
               $files = Input::file('images');
               
               if(is_array($files)){
                   $file_count = count($files);
                    \Log::info($file_count);
                 foreach($files as $file) { 
                         $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                         \Log::info($filename);
                         $file->storeAs('westims/pictures/' . $row->site_id . '/' . $row->id, $filename);
                 }
               } else {
                   $filename = str_pad($file_count, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            Input::file('images')->storeAs('westims/pictures/' . $row->site_id . '/' . $row->id, $filename);
               }
```

I also set 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"  in my blade.

I was able to select 2 files, but when I tried to save them, only one was saved.

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not solve your problem, [edit]ing your question to add your HTML and controller PHP will help others diagnose the problem.

Comment: I still am only seeing one file when I try to save;  I am creating the file widget in my controller, and able to set it to multiple, but still I am only able to upload one 1 image.  Could my Laravel version (5.3.31) bee too low?

Comment: I assume if you are using software that's >5 years old you have a good reason for doing so. But as I said above, nobody can help without seeing any code.